# Equivalent to /proc/pid/status on windows

Tags: windows, command-line

I use /proc/pid/status |grep VmRSS on Linux to find out the memory usage of specific process.

Is it possible to do the same thing on Windows?

Answer (score 3):

`tasklist /FI "PID eq ABCD" /FO csv` - displays very basic info for a process; you can pipe it through `findstr` to get just the line/string for the memory

Answer (score 0):

I think the Sysinternals tool *pslist* might help you.

Reference: [pslist](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896682)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: OK, I edited the answer. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I was thinking of using windows command window and not an external application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the memory usage of a process you can run the below script via a batch file; using powershell.exe as an example:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=5 delims= " %%A in ('tasklist /NH /FI "ImageName Eq powershell.exe"') do (
    echo %%A K
)
```